# Access Django from outside

Tags: python, django

I installed Django on my Ubuntu Server 14 as a development tool.
I want to access Django outside my server by using the URL http://my_server_ip:82 on any computer.

So I ran the command python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:82.

But when I try to connect to http://my_server_ip:82 from another computer, it doesn't work..

I also :
- allowed port 82 by using ufw allow in 82 and ufw allow out 82.
- wrote ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] in settings.py

I read many and many topics dealing with this problem but it finally worked in many cases. I tried everything but nothing seems to work..
Would you have any solutions ?

Thanks !

Comment: "does not work" is not very specific. Please elaborate.

Comment: I have a ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT response. I cannot access to  http://my_server_ip:82

Comment: Both of your computers are connected to same network?

Comment: Most likely not django specific. this is the network or a firewall.

Comment: No, Django is installed on a web host server. And I'd like to access it from any computer, like I do for my web applications installed on Apache

Comment: @W.Mann That's what I thought but I checked my firewall and added ufw allow in 82 and ufw allow out 82 rules

Comment: @Julien have you confirmed that the issue is Django specific? if you have something else (like netcat) listening on 82, can the other machine see it?

Comment: Actually, the error code looks like an error code of squid. Disabling using the proxy server for that IP in your browser could help.

Comment: It seems to be specific to Django since I can access to the homepage of my server, to Nagios, to Mysql and Postgresql databases and so on

Comment: do you have any Django logging?  Does `runserver` display any output when hitting the URL?

Comment: On my server, when i type lynx http://localhost:82 or http://my_ip_server:82 it's ok I have the django response. So I don't think it could be a logging problem.

Comment: what happens if you change the port to something like `8080`?

Comment: You could try choosing a port number > 1024 instead of 82.

Comment: I tried port 8000 (I added the rules in the firewall) but same thing...

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to use the builtin Django webserver in a production setting. 
I would encourage you to check alternatives like Apache, Spawning, Gunigorn, Cherokee or so.

Please refer to the documentation
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port

Comment: I know, but that is only for a test. After I will use Apache to make it work in production

Comment: did you try running it then with super-user priviledges? Ports below a certain number require special priviledges.

Comment: Unfortunately when I do "ufw status verbose", it says that my port 82 is opened.